# YOLOv7 segmentation: error with using pre-trained weights

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, yolo

I would like to use YOLOv7 for segmentation on my custom dataset and custom classes. 
I am already able to run the 'normal' YOLO version with my data and using the `yolov7.pt` weights.
But when I am using the `yolov7-mask.pt` weights, I end up having an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 616, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "train.py", line 71, in train
    run_id = torch.load(weights, map_location=device).get('wandb_id') if weights.endswith('.pt') and os.path.isfile(weights) else None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 789, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1131, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1124, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Merge' on <module 'models.common' from '/content/yolov7/models/common.py'>
```

I also saw that [this error is not specific to me, but not a solution.](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/1076)
Also, [this tutorial](https://medium.com/augmented-startups/train-yolov7-segmentation-on-custom-data-b91237bd2a29) does not use pre-trained weights and does not mention why it does so.

When I do not use pretrained weights the code compiles, but I did not check yet how good it is (I assume will take much longer to train).

Any advice will be appreciated.